# char_array assignment in Ada

Tags: ada

In a Ada program with simple char array (Interfaces.C.char array) declaration,

```
package C renames Interfaces.C;
Msg : C.Char_Array(1..50) := (others => C.To_C(Item=>ASCII.NUL));
```

Got runtime exception **"length check failed"** at the following assignment:

```
Msg := C.To_C(Item => "UNKNOWN ERROR",Append_Nul => True));
```

What is wrong in the above assignment which raised the exception? Is there any simple one-liner way through which I can write smaller assignments to the char array directly like the one above?

Comment: `Msg'Length` is 50. What is the length of the value you're trying to assign to it?

Comment: @Keith Thompson I want to assign a value which is less than 50, and I want rest remaining elements to be automatically filled with null (ASCII.NUL) value. So here like Interfaces.C provides a function **To_C** to convert Ada **Strings** into **char_array** which I used here and the String I used is less than 50 chars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see the ARM. Annex [B.3](http://www.adaic.com/standards/05rm/html/RM-B-3.html#).

Other than the function To_C there is also a procedure To_C.

First declare a size_t variable to hold the returned value:

```
   Count : Size_T;
```

then:

```
   C.To_C(Item => "UNKNOWN ERROR",
          Target => Msg,
          Count => Count,
          Append_Nul => True);
```